# Docker error: "host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```yaml
version: '3.6'

services:
  vpn-proxy: # docker exec -it vpn-proxy /bin/sh
    container_name: vpn-proxy
    build:
      context: ../../vpn-proxy
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:13194:13194"
    logging:
      driver: json-file
    #command: -v UDP4-RECVFROM:13194,fork UDP4-SENDTO:172.17.0.1:1194
    command: TCP-LISTEN:13194,fork TCP:172.17.0.1:1194
    restart: always
  openvpn: # docker exec -it openvpn /bin/sh
    image: kylemanna/openvpn
    container_name: openvpn
    environment:
      DEBUG: '0'
    ports:
      - "1194:1194/udp"
    volumes:
      - ../../openvpn/scripts:/scripts
      - ../../data/output:/output
    network_mode: host
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    command: /scripts/run-vpn.sh
    restart: always
```

> ERROR: for openvpn  "host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings
> docker.errors.InvalidArgument: "host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings

When I run my up.sh file, I get the error as above.

Answer (score 7):

The error message is telling you that you can't use `network_mode: host` and `ports` in the same service, you need to make a choice.

Your `openvpn` service has a `1194:1194/udp` **port binding**. This is used to bind a port of the host to a port of the container.
But as you used the **host networking mode**, the container will use the host's *networking interfaces*, making your port bindings useless as the container will have access to the host's ports.

You could remove the `ports` section of your service but as the *host networking mode* is generally not recommended you should try to use port bindings instead.

Comment: Can you share an example of how I should edit?

Comment: Delete the line that says `network_mode: host`.

Comment: network_mode: tunnelblick won't connect to vpn after deleting host